# Maximum Number of Patterns That Fit in a Space

Tags: algorithm

Suppose that you have a boolean, `n`-by-`m`, randomly-initialized array `A`, and suppose that you have a boolean, `p`-by-`q`, randomly-initialized array `B`, where `p <= n` and `q <= m`.

I want to know the maximum number of `B`s that *fit* in `A`: I say that `B` fits in `A` if `not (A[k + i, l + j] and B[i, j])` is `true` for every `0 <= i < p` and every `0 <= j < q`, where `0 <= k < n - p` and `0 <= l < m - q`.

In simpler words, I have a pattern and a map with obstructions, and I want to know the maximum number of patterns that fit in said map. I use the convention that `true` and `false` represent occupied and unoccupied space, respectively.

I am currently tackling this problem via recursion, but it is extraordinarily inefficient. I wonder if there is a better approach. I would appreciate even a reference.

**Edit 1**: I am interested in the maximum number of non-overlapping `B`s.

**Edit 2**: Let `A` be the following array:

[image]

Let `B` be the following array:

[image]

Notice that I let `B` and its center be of different colors for visualization purposes only.

Then I can fit `B`s into `A` in the following two ways:

[image]
[image]

In the first image, I was able to fit six `B`s. However, in the second image, I was able to fit nine. I am interested in the maximum number.

Comment: If you do a 2D convolution with one matrix as is and the diagonal mirror image of the other, the entries equal to the number of ones in the pattern give the positions of the matches. Not sure if maximum means non overlapping though.

Comment: Can you add an example? And what is the complexity of your current solution? How big can these matrixes be?

Comment: @juvian, I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward approach I can think of would be worst-case *O(mnpq)*. Think of matrix `B` as a template which lays on top of matrix `A`. For each position `x,y` in `A` where `B` can be placed with it's top left corner on that position (`x,y`) so that all of matrix `B` is contained within `A` (there are *(m-p)(n-q)* of these positions), check that for each `0<=i<p` and `0<=j<q`, `B[i][j]` and `A[x+i][y+j]` are not both `1`. Count the number of locations where this occurs. This code would use four nested `if` loops, and avoid recursion altogether.

If `A` happens to be sparse (few positions are `true`), it would be more efficient to work backwards, noting locations where `B` cannot be placed. Begin with a matrix `C` of size `A` initialized to `true`. Scan `A` for all positions where `A[x][y]` is true, and note values where if the upper-left corner of `B` were to be placed, a `true` in `B` would collide with a `true` in `A`. Set all values of `C` where this occurs equal to `false`. Once completed, summing matrix `C` will provide you with the number of locations where no collisions occur.